# What browsers does bluebird support?

Tags: bluebird

I checked the bluebird website was not able to find an answer.  I then checked the GitHub issues and found an old, broken link with browser support.

What browsers and browser versions does bluebird support?

Comment: From their website: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/install.html#supported-platforms

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately that section doesn't show up when Google searching the site.  As I already knew how to install, I never checked Installation section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Bluebird supports:** Internet Explorer 7 and up, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Edge and Node (0.8+).

The following are also maintained but not tested regularly: Firefox Extensions, Chrome Extensions, Edge Extensions, React Native, Electron, Mobile Safari, Mobile Chrome, Mobile Chrome on iOS, Android Browesr, Rhino and a bunch of other environments.

It actually runs on Netscape 7 and IE6 just fine - I ran the tests just for the lols.

We might drop support for some older platforms in the future but honestly we'll probably support these platforms for good. Petka wrote the code in such a way that maintaining support for old platforms is not a particular challenge - most of the work is on new platforms with new scheduling mechanisms (like beta versions of Safari iOS breaking stuff).

If you find a platform bluebird does not run on, issues are appreciated and pull requests are entertained.

Source: I'm a bluebird contributor.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. Would it be possible to put this on the website? Perhaps in the section Rocket Hazmat commented with.

Comment: What part is missing in the website section?

Comment: Could you link me to where it is listed on the website?

Comment: awesome, bluebird rocks!